# Conteúdo de uma div excedendo a outra div

Tags: javascript, html, css

No formulário há 3 divs, (divvisualizar > div > divconteudoemail) conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
<div id="divvisualizar" style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid rgb(85, 85, 85); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 100; top: 3%; left: 25%; position: absolute; width: 50%; box-shadow: rgb(20, 20, 20) 4px 4px 20px 0px; border-radius: 5px; height: 90%;">

    <div tipo="_div" style="padding: 3px; background-color: rgb(35, 75, 116);" class="dashed-black-border col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="_div4"><span id="span4" tipo="span" title="Fechar" onclick="span4_onclick(this)" style="float: right; color: white; font-weight: bold; cursor: pointer;;">X
    </span>
    </div>


     <div tipo="_div" style="background-color: rgb(240, 255, 255);" class="dashed-black-border col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="divcabecalho">
        <div tipo="_div" style="margin-top: 5px; padding: 0px;" class="dashed-black-border col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="_div5">
            <label tipo="_label" style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 5px; padding: 5px;" class="control-label dashed-black-border col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" id="_label7">Mensagem :</label>
            <label tipo="_label" style="text-align: left; margin-top: 5px; padding: 5px;" class="control-label dashed-black-border col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10" id="lblmensagem">Mensagem: Teste</label>
        </div>
        <div tipo="_div" style="margin-top: 5px; padding: 0px;" class="dashed-black-border col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="_div6">
            <label tipo="_label" style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 5px; padding: 5px;" class="control-label dashed-black-border col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" id="_label8">Assunto :</label>
            <label tipo="_label" style="text-align: left; margin-top: 5px; padding: 5px;" class="control-label dashed-black-border col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8" id="lblassunto">Assunto: Teste</label>
        </div>
        <div tipo="_div" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;" class="dashed-black-border col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10" id="divanexos">
            <label tipo="_label" style="margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; font-weight: bold;" class="control-label dashed-black-border col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2" id="_label9">Anexos :
            </label>
            <div style='margin:3px; 0px; 0px; 5px; padding: 1%; cursor:pointer; border: 1px solid rgb(85, 85, 85); font-size: 11px; border-radius: 5px; display:inline-block;'>98852671.pdf
            </div>

        </div>
     </div>

     <div tipo="_div" style="margin-top: 5px; height: 100%; width: 100%;" class="dashed-black-border col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="div">

        <div tipo="_div" style="padding: 2% 6%; border: 1px solid rgb(85, 85, 85); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); box-shadow: rgb(20, 20, 20) 4px 4px 20px 0px; border-radius: 2px; height: 100%; width: 100%;  box-sizing: border-box; word-break: break-all; overflow-y: auto;" class="dashed-black-border col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="   divconteudoemail">TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE



                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETEVTESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE
                        FIM
        </div>

     </div>

 </div>
```

Acontece que o conteúdo que é inserido na div "divconteudoemail" é dinamico, pode ser extenso ou não, o problema esta sendo quando tem muito conteudo, ele estoura o tamanho da div principal (divvisualizacao).

Exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procurei alguns tópico já aberto, tentei utilizar o "white-space: pre-wrap;" porém sem sucesso.

Comment: Já tentou utilizar no css "word-wrap: break-word;" ?

Comment: Tentei sim!! Não funcionou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize flexbox com direção de coluna na div `#div` (que é a div onde está a div `#divconteudoemail`) e adicione `flex: 1` na div `#divconteudoemail` além de outras propriedades para ajustar espaçamentos. Desta forma, a div terá altura automática, não importando o que estiver dentro da div `#div`. Isso porque a propriedade `flex: 1` (ou `flex-grow: 1`) faz com que o elemento ocupe todo espaço restante da div (no seu caso, o espaço vertical).

> Não precisa nem colocar `box-sizing: border-box` porque o Bootstrap já
>   faz isso.

Remova também o `overflow-x: auto;` e o `height: 100%`, e adicione `overflow: auto;`, `word-break: break-all;` (para quebrar string longas) e `margin-top: 15px;` (só se for o caso, para espaçar do cabeçalho).

É bom aprender um pouco de flexbox pois tudo fica mais simples. Veja:

```css
#divvisualizar{
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid rgb(85, 85, 85);
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   z-index: 100;
   top: 3%;
   left: 25%;
   position: absolute;
   width: 50%;
   box-shadow: rgb(20, 20, 20) 4px 4px 20px 0px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   height: 90%;
}

#div{
   margin-top: 5px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   padding-bottom: 22px;
}

#divconteudoemail{
   flex: 1;
   padding: 2% 6%;
   border: 1px solid rgb(85, 85, 85);
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   box-shadow: rgb(20, 20, 20) 4px 4px 20px 0px;
   border-radius: 2px;
   width: 100%;
   word-break: break-all;
   overflow: auto;
   margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="divvisualizar">

     <div tipo="_div" class="dashed-black-border col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="div">
        <div>
         mensagem
         <br>
         qualquer coisa aqui
        </div>
        <div tipo="_div" class="dashed-black-border col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="divconteudoemail">TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE


                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETEVTESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

        </div>

     </div>

 </div>
```

**Agora um exemplo sem nada acima da div, com o mesmo CSS do exemplo anterior:**

```css
#divvisualizar{
   padding: 5px;
   border: 1px solid rgb(85, 85, 85);
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   z-index: 100;
   top: 3%;
   left: 25%;
   position: absolute;
   width: 50%;
   box-shadow: rgb(20, 20, 20) 4px 4px 20px 0px;
   border-radius: 5px;
   height: 90%;
}

#div{
   margin-top: 5px;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   padding-bottom: 22px;
}

#divconteudoemail{
   flex: 1;
   padding: 2% 6%;
   border: 1px solid rgb(85, 85, 85);
   background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
   box-shadow: rgb(20, 20, 20) 4px 4px 20px 0px;
   border-radius: 2px;
   width: 100%;
   word-break: break-all;
   overflow: auto;
   margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="divvisualizar">

     <div tipo="_div" class="dashed-black-border col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="div">
        <div tipo="_div" class="dashed-black-border col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="divconteudoemail">TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE


                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETEVTESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                            TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

        </div>

     </div>

 </div>
```

> Coloquei também um `padding-bottom: 22px;` na div `#div` para dar um
>   espaçamento da borda de baixo. Esse valor você pode alterar se quiser.

Comment: Cara deu certinho suar orientações, muito obrigado. Cometi uma falha, havia um conteudo acima que era gerado pelo framework, acabei não demonstrando no código, você previu isso e resolveu o problema, vou estar editando a questão, desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 6):

Cara tira o overflow-x, e coloca `box-sizing: border-box` para o `padding` não  somar a largura total do container, de usa  `word-break: break-all;` para quebrar palavras grandes mais largas que o container. Eu adicionei tb `overflow-y: auto;` para o texto não estourar o container na vertical, então ele cria a barra de rolagem vertical de forma automática apenas caso necessário.

```html
<div id="divvisualizar" style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid rgb(85, 85, 85); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 100; top: 3%; left: 25%; position: absolute; width: 50%; box-shadow: rgb(20, 20, 20) 4px 4px 20px 0px; border-radius: 5px; height: 90%;">

    <div tipo="_div" style="margin-top: 5px; height: 100%; width: 100%;" class="dashed-black-border col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="div">

       <div tipo="_div" style="padding: 2% 6%; border: 1px solid rgb(85, 85, 85); background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); box-shadow: rgb(20, 20, 20) 4px 4px 20px 0px; border-radius: 2px; height: 100%; width: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; word-break: break-all; overflow-y: auto;" class="dashed-black-border col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" id="   divconteudoemail">TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE



                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETEVTESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

                           TESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETETESTETESTESTESTESTESSTESTESETE

       </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Adicione o respectivo trecho do código, houve a quebra de palavra certinha, não gerou o scroll em baixo, porém o conteudo da "divconteudoemail" ainda continua excedendo o tamanho da divprincipal (divvisualizar).

Comment: @VictorHenrique cara no exemplo aqui vc pode ver que o conteúdo não vaza de dentro da div principal, vc deve ter colocado algum código a mais ai ou a menos na pergunta que fez, ou então está testando em uma condição diferente da que perguntou... É só executar o meu código aqui que vc vai ver que nada "vaza" https://prnt.sc/rahh2q veja a imagem

Comment: realmente eu editei o codigo postado e funcionou, provavelmente o problema é o restante do conteudo por traz, vou editar a publicação.

Comment: editei a publicação, ja com suas orietações.

Comment: @VictorHenrique meu editar colocando uma imagem não adianta nada, como vc espera que de para resolver com código vendo uma imagem? vc tem que colocar o mínimo de código que de para simular a sua situação ai

Comment: Acontece que utilizo um framework, não consigo gerar o html/css de todo conteúdo, achei que seria possivel com os elementos que estão sendo manipulados em questão, onde os mesmos possuem o código acima. Mas obrigado de toda forma.

Comment: Com o código da sua pergunta o que da para te responder é isso.... Vc pode testar colocando na div divconteudoemail um max-height: 100%, mas acho que não vai funcionar... em último caso vc pode colocar para ela um valor fixo  em PX de height, tipo heigh: 200px que vai funcionar

Comment: Sim eu entendo, corrigi minha falha, havia um conteudo acima que era gerado pelo framework, não me atentei em demonstrar no codigo de exemplo, possivelmente dificultou na interpretação e resolução, foi corrido o código e já deu tudo certo. obrigado.